# Tax for income from outside of country in Sweden

Tags: taxes, sweden, students

I'm a foreign and non-EU student in Sweden (Sorry! I don't speak Swedish yet but learning it), I have 2 question about taxes:

1. Should I pay tax for the money which my parent send me for studying and living to my Swedish bank account (they will send money from Russia)? Is there any limit for amount they send monthly?
2. I have an online website and I sell digital products on it to worldwide customers, I use a USA based company to process online payments for my website, and this company send my earnings to my Russian bank (in Russia) monthly, now if I change the bank and ask that company to send my earnings to my Swedish bank in Sweden, then should I pay tax for it in Sweden?

Comment: Quite a lot of information seems [to be available in English](http://www.skatteverket.se/download/18.71004e4c133e23bf6db800030152/10412.pdf). Apparently, there is no gift tax but the income you derive from your website would presumably be taxable in any case (i.e. even if you are paid in Russia although it's obviously more difficult for the Swedish tax office to track this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) No, you do not need to pay taxes for money your parents send to you;
they have already been taxed. It is not counted as income, as you do not perform any work to get this.

2) This should be taxed in some country, either Russia or Sweden. 
As pointed out, it is hard to track, but "Skatteverket" might be curious about where money on your Swedish bank account comes from. The earnings from your company, has these been taxed in United states or Russia?

You can always transfer money between personal accounts, if they have already been taxed. Earnings should not be taxed twice.